# What happens when you don't define STATICFILES_DIR in django?

Tags: python, django, static

I use django and my application works, when I change the style.css the app changes etc.

However, I recently found out that I didn't define `STATICFILES_DIR`, I only defined

```
STATIC_URL  = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Which is only for `collectstatic`.

But now I'm wondering, how does django know where to look for the static files?

Specifically in the `polls/static/polls` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django will look for a directory named `static` in each of your apps by default. More on this later.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/):

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our static files
>   directly in my_app/static/ (rather than creating another my_app
>   subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use
>   the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a
>   static file with the same name in a different application, Django
>   would be unable to distinguish between them.

The key part being

> ...Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches...

There are Django libraries called "static file finders" that help with this process. You can configure them by modifying the installed apps in your Django configuration file.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders), they're actually undocumented, because they are considered private. However, you *can* [look at the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py) for those "finders" on GitHub.

Django projects are composed of modules called apps. Each app contains some default files when you generate it. Although there is configuration, there's plenty of convention about Django too. For example, the views.py file. Another such convention is your app's static directories folder.

Your `STATICFILES_DIR` array allows you to add additional places for you to put your static files. This is useful, as you'll see when you prepare to deploy, because of the way Django handles static files in a real-world environment.

It's totally optional, but it's there to make your life easier later.

Comment: ahhhhh ok thanks, and once you define a `STATICFILES_DIR` this doesn't happen anymore, I see, thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. I've added some more information, too.